# Is it possible to decrease the usage in Metered Billing Plan ( using Laravel Cashier - Stripe)

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am creating an appointment application where users billed per appointment, sometime the users will cancel the subscription. In that time we need to decrease the usage, is the right way to do it? if so is there any facility for that in Laravel Cashier?

In the Stripe Documentation, it says about an [Action ENUM](https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create), Can we use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use the `set` instead of increment:

In the source code we can see the following on a [`SubscriptionItem#reportUsage`](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/688204edc7567b5c6516512d61672b6921f1d01b/src/SubscriptionItem.php#L197):

```php
    public function reportUsage($quantity = 1, $timestamp = null)
    {
        $timestamp = $timestamp instanceof DateTimeInterface ? $timestamp->getTimestamp() : $timestamp;

        return $this->subscription->owner->stripe()->subscriptionItems->createUsageRecord($this->stripe_id, [
            'quantity' => $quantity,
            'action' => $timestamp ? 'set' : 'increment',
            'timestamp' => $timestamp ?? time(),
        ]);
    }
```

which is called by [`Subscription#reportUsage`](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/688204edc7567b5c6516512d61672b6921f1d01b/src/Subscription.php#L523)

```php
    public function reportUsage($quantity = 1, $timestamp = null, $price = null)
    {
        if (! $price) {
            $this->guardAgainstMultiplePrices();
        }

        return $this->findItemOrFail($price ?? $this->stripe_price)->reportUsage($quantity, $timestamp);
    }
```

So if you want to decrement you would just get the current usage and set a new usage, you have to include the timestamp parameter to use `set` instead of increment:

```php
// get current usage
$newUsage = $currentUsage - $decrement;

$user = User::find(1);

$user->subscription('default')->reportUsage($newUsage, time());
```

Comment: Alex, in your final example line I think the `$timestamp` arg needs to be included to trigger the `'set'` action, right?

Comment: Good catch, I read that ternary backwards for some reason.

Comment: @AlexHarris I tried your code, but it adding new value to the old value 

here is my code

`$user = User::where('id',$appointmentById->user_id)->first();

 $usageRecords = $user->subscription('default')->usageRecords();

        $usageRecordsNew = json_decode($usageRecords);
        $newValue = $usageRecords[0]->total_usage -1;
        $user->subscription('default')->reportUsage($newValue, time());`

Comment: The Stripe API "...set action will overwrite the usage quantity at that timestamp", so you have to provide the **exact same** timestamp if you want to change a specific record. Took me a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Alex Harris is a good example of this using Cashier, as asked. To generalize this to other Stripe integrations, this is supported by using `action=set` when creating usage records ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create#usage_record_create-action)):

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscription_items/si_123/usage_records \
  -u sk_test_456: \
  -d quantity=100 \
  -d action=set \
  -d timestamp=1571252444
```